# Resources for writing a recursive descent parser by hand

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

I'm looking to write a recursive descent parser by hand and I'm looking for good resources on how to structure it, algorithms, etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial on codeproject under "Compiler Patterns".  Lately, you can even just Google "compiler patterns".

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286121/Compiler-Patterns

The article covers most aspects of building a simple compiler (the back-end, the BNF, and the patterns used to implement the various BNF rules), but is not very heavy on theory, or even on why a recursive descent compiler works to convert language input into code.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest "Crafting a Compiler" by Charles N. Fischer and Richard J. LeBlanc.

Edit. This is an updated version: [http://www.amazon.com/Crafting-Compiler-Charles-N-Fischer/dp/0136067050/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1258514561&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136067050)